# Dark Mode toggle switch as a user style using DOM ( Tamper monkey )

Tags: javascript, css, dom, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to create a userscript for an ancient website. I am using tampermonkey to wite style and js.

This is the script I have currently written. It is to change font etc. It works well.

Now, I want to create a darkmode switch. Which when triggered makes body bgcolor black and text white and vice versa.

```
let styleSheet = `

/* Changes body font to Lexend Deca */
body {
font-family: "Lexend Deca",sans-serif !important;
}

/* gives fluidity to text and increase font size */
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  html {
    font-size: calc(16px + 6 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680));
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  html {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}
`;

(function () {
/* Import Lexand Deca Font from Google Fonts */
    let lexfont = document.createElement('link');
    lexfont.rel = 'stylesheet';
    lexfont.href = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap';
    document.head.appendChild(lexfont);


/* Creates Style Sheet where all styles are defined */    
  let s = document.createElement('style');
  s.type = "text/css";
  s.innerHTML = styleSheet;
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

This website don't use concepts like id & class. It uses bgcolor.

```
 <BODY BGCOLOR="#ffffff">
```

I want to place a toggleable switch which could toggle dark & light mode. How do I switch style ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself.

```
/* Dark Mode */

/* Create a Button */

var btn2 = document.createElement('BUTTON');
btn2.innerHTML = 'Toggle Dark Mode';
   btn2.classList.add('btn-toggle')
document.body.appendChild(btn2);

/* give body A class name */

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = 'dark-theme || light-theme';

/* js for button toggle */

    const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
});
```